# Excel custom hyperlink for each cell in range using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module that removes all formulas from an entire sheet and then, it should, create a hyperlink formula on each cell using the cell value.

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")

ws1.Range("B33:F533").Value = ws1.Range("B33:F533").Value


For Each i In ws1.Range("B33:B533")

i.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""https://somelocation/" & i.Value & """,""" & i.Value & """)"

Next


End Sub
```

EDIT: It's now working perfectly. Thanks For all the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i.Formula = "=HYPERLINK('https://somelocation/"&i.Value&","& i.Value"')"
```

Has an error in the formula. At the `i.Value"')` you are missing `&`, `i.Value & "'`. The correct one, that 'compiles', is added below:

```
i.Formula = "=HYPERLINK('https://somelocation/" & i.Value & "," & i.Value & "')"
```

Also it is worth noting that instead of writing `"&i.Value&"` and let the VBA IDE add the spaces, it is better to do it yourself, eg: `" & i.Value & "`.

You're code has 2 flaws, you should add the last `&` to get a syntax correct formula, and add spaces between the `"` and `&`, or else VBA won't see it is right.

**Edit; a third flaw:**

The line to create the formula is wrong too. Let's break it down:
`"=HYPERLINK('https://somelocation/" & i.Value & "," & i.Value & "')"`

The parameter in the formula would be:
`'https://somelocation/" & i.Value & "," & i.Value & "'` so an output example of this line could be `'https://somelocation/1,1'`. At first, I thought you are writing an URL with a comma, alright..? But then I looked at the `HYPERLINK` function in Excel and it requires two parameters. You are only giving one parameter. Excel formulas also expect a double quote instead of a single quote. You can escape a double quote in VBA like this `""`.

The correct line should be:

`i.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""https://somelocation/" & i.Value & """,""" & i.Value & """)"`

Comment: Your method did fix the compile error but now  I get a "Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error" on the same line

Comment: You are using single quotes in the formula. It expects double quotes. You can escape a double quote in VBA by typing `""`. So this line should become `"=HYPERLINK(""https://somelocation/" & i.Value & """,""" & i.Value & """)"`.